# Area 51: automatically detect the word 'for' in the proposal description

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, site-proposal

In [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), the description automatically begins with the word "For", and sometimes users, when writing the description of the proposal, do not realize this and write "for" *again*, resulting in "for for"....

**The point:** Can we have Area51 detect "for" at the beginning and edit it out automatically?

An example:

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: You could also comment on the proposal stating that there's an extra 'for'.

Comment: Computers are supposed to make things easier for humans! It's far less effort to have the computer do it when relevant - at the point it's prefixed, just make it replace `^(?i:for )?` with `For ` and it solves the problem for everyone, instead of wasting time manually commenting and editing each time it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leading `"for "`'s are stripped now.